# How to prove omitted variable bias is zero when the covariance between the omitted variable and other exogenous variables is zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to prove omitted variable bias is zero when the covariance between the omitted variable and other exogenous variables is zero?

The following is from wiki and I couldn't prove that 
 "$z$ is correlated with any of the included variables in the matrix $X$" $\iff$ $E[ X'Z | X ]=0$

> As an example, consider a linear model of the form
>   $$y_i = x_i \beta + z_i \delta + u_i,\qquad i = 1,\dots,n$$
>   If the independent variable ''z'' is omitted from the regression, then the estimated values of the response parameters of the other independent variables will be given by the usual least squares calculation:
>   $$\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y\,$$
>
> Substituting for ''Y'' based on the assumed linear model,
>   :
>   \begin{align}
> \hat{\beta} & = (X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta+Z\delta+U) \\
> & =(X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'Z\delta + (X'X)^{-1}X'U \\
> & =\beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'Z\delta + (X'X)^{-1}X'U.
> \end{align}
>
> On taking expectations, the contribution of the final term is zero; this follows from the assumption that ''U'' is uncorrelated with the regressors ''X''. On simplifying the remaining terms:
>   :
>   \begin{align}
> E[ \hat{\beta} | X ] & = \beta + (X'X)^{-1}E[ X'Z | X ]\delta \\
> & = \beta + \text{bias}.
> \end{align}
>
> The second term after the equal sign is the omitted-variable bias in this case, which is non-zero if the omitted variable ''z'' is correlated with any of the included variables in the matrix ''X'' (that is, if ''X'Z'' does not equal a vector of zeroes). Note that the bias is equal to the weighted portion of $z_i $which is "explained" by $x_i$.

Link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias